# Importing user-friendly Excel sheet into a SQL Server table that has many foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, sqlbulkcopy, sqldataadapter

I have an Excel sheet that is populated by HR employee with thousands of client records it looks like this one:

[User Friendly Excel Sheet Example Screenshot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=148orif&s=8#.VXJSHEZKVfB)

My client's SQL Server table schema looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients] (
[ID]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]          NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Photo]         VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL,
[PolicyID]      INT            NOT NULL,
[BirthDay]      DATE           NOT NULL,
[Gender]        BIT            NOT NULL,
[Title]         NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[Nationality]   NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Relationship]  NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[ClassID]       INT            NOT NULL,
[SponsorID]     INT            NULL,
[HRID]          INT            NOT NULL,
[Active]        BIT            CONSTRAINT [DF_Clients_Active] DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
[StartingDate]  DATE           NOT NULL,
[EndingDate]    DATE           NOT NULL,
[AddingDate]    DATETIME       NOT NULL,
[Creator]       INT            NOT NULL,
[UniqueID]      NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[PassportNo]    NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Clients] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Clients_Clients] FOREIGN KEY ([SponsorID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clients] ([ID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Clients_Employees] FOREIGN KEY ([HRID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([ID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Clients_Employees1] FOREIGN KEY ([Creator]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([ID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Clients_Policy] FOREIGN KEY ([PolicyID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Policy] ([ID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Clients_Classes] FOREIGN KEY ([ClassID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Classes] ([ID])
);
```

What is the best approach to achieve such inserts?

I've tried using `SqlBulkCopy` but it doesn't allow any manipulation on the inserted rows.

I've tried also using `SqlAdapter.Update(Datatable)` but it failed since I've read the Excel sheet using `ExcelDataReader` then tried to add some columns like `Creator` and `Adding Date` at runtime and when I tried to run `Adapter.Update(ModifiedDatatable)` it throws an exception

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows

When I tried to use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert this Excel sheet it worked as expected

[Excel Sheet with Foreign Keys Screenshot](http://i61.tinypic.com/21opvrb.png)

But it's not right to force the end user to put some foreign keys in the Excel sheet before import.

Notice:

Sorry for uploading screenshots to Tinypic but I couldn't upload them here because of my Rep Points.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using the OPENROWSET command to treat the Excel sheet as a linked server table, and from there you can write any query you need using it as a source. So you could just INSERT the records to append them to the end of a SQL table or you could use MERGE if you want to do UPSERT (INSERT/UPDATE) behavior.

Comment: Thanks @JosephGagliardo "Given Excels lack of true data types, I am not a big fan of the OPENROWSET approach to your problem. I've seen more than than enough problems with numbers being mistaken for text and nulling out when they arrive in SQL to go with Rob's suggestion.

I have no doubt OPENROWSET would miss some data, especially if you're using 64 bit sql, which does not like Excel one bit.
Brandie Tarvin, MCITP Database Administrator" .... www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1238593-1292-1.aspx ... i've no experience with OPENROWSET command but it looks not the best approach out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be creating an SSIS package in this scenario. SSIS can read from Excel, and you can get it to query the database for the extra information to build a valid dataset that will not violate the FK constraints.